# Double SSH and execute interactive shell

Tags: bash, ssh, shell

I need a bash script to ssh into server a then server b then execute an interactive shell.

This is what I have:

```
ssh -t -t server-a.com exec "ssh -t -t server-b.com <<<EOF
cd /pylons/web/app/
. envs/bin/activate
paster shell /lib/config.ini
EOF
```

It goes all the way but then "hangs" on the shell. I can type but I get no output.

I also tried the below. It stops after it connects to server-a.com

```
ssh -t -t server-a.com exec "ssh -t -t server-b.com "
cd /pylons/web/app/
. envs/bin/activate
paster shell /lib/config.ini""
```

Comment: have you discounted using ssh proxycommand ?

Comment: Sirex I don't think that is feasible in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `<<` instead of `<<<`.

Or perhaps:

```
ssh -t -t server-a.com ssh -t -t server-b.com '"
cd /pylons/web/app/
. envs/bin/activate
paster shell /lib/config.ini "'
```

Comment: Same thing. The paster shell loads up but when I type something and hit enter nothing happens... it hangs.

Comment: @Bruno ok. I've edited my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Your alternate version, only connects to server-a.com and stops.

Comment: @Bruno, need to quote again because of 2 ssh's.

Comment: your are the man! Worked like a charm!