# Bash script: for loop after two ssh commands

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

Following [Double SSH and execute interactive shell](https://superuser.com/questions/941632/double-ssh-and-execute-interactive-shell?newreg=35399132308a4419aac09972a800ee33), I need to run two type of loops after two ssh commands:

```
#!/bin/bash/expect
ssh -t -t server.com ssh -t -t virtualHostName '"

declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3");
for a in "${arr[@]}" ; do echo $a; done;

for a in $(arp -a | tail -n+2 | cut -d\  -f1)
do
    echo "Connected to $a"
done

#arp -a #This works
#traceroute admin #This works
echo Terminating "'
```

However, the first loop is not printing out anything and the second loop returns (even though it run normally if I copy and paste the loop on the terminal after I ssh manually):

```
bash: -c: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `virtualHostName.admin'
```

Comment: Maybe because your double quotes don't start and end where you think they do? In the linked answer there were no "inner" double quotes. I guess in your case *here document* syntax may be better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks you're probably right. How can I go about doing this? I tried `CMDS=$(cat <<CMD 
declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3");
for a in "${arr[@]}" ; do echo $a; done;
CMD 
)` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a problem with the quotes as @Kamil Maciorowski mentioned.

For now I'll just replace every single quote with "\"" and add \ in front of every $ per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233938/ssh-meremote-script-with-a-for-loop-and-variables-problem-with-variable-e ...